# Pygame window not opening

Tags: python, pygame

I have python 3.8 and pygame installed. I am using Pycharm. On my Windows desktop pc at home, everything works perfectly as intended. However on my mac, when I run my code, the python.app icon starts jumping in my dock indefinitely but no window is opening. There are no errors, and everything else works perfectly fine. Just the window doesn't open.

[image: To illustrate what I mean:]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same issue.  Go to the bottom right of the pyCharm screen and click on Python3.8 .

A list with interpreter settings should appear.
Go to project interpreter and double click on the version of Pygame you are running and update it to 2.0.0dev6.

Comment: I have python 3.8.5. and still, my window does not show up when I start the program...

Answer (score 1):

Rosendo and junjia are correct, you need to install pygame 2.0.0. I was experiencing the same issue (window wasn't opening...).  The exact command for mac users:

`pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your python version is not match with your pygame version. 
If your are using Python 3.8, please update your pygame to 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In IDLE make sure you start with `pygame.init()`